# curl_multi_exec in php

Tags: php, curl

Experience with the php curl_multi_exec($m,$active) function, seems to confirm that the $active will always go down by one between calls, even if two websites are finished. But is it guaranteed, when using this function, that if you do some really long code in between two calls, that the $active will always drop by one from its last value?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/curl_multi_exec) nor the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html) of the [underlying](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/curl/multi.c#L229) cURL function `curl_multi_perform()` says anything about `$active` only being decremented by 1 between calls, so it's probably just coincidence and you should certainly not rely on it as it may change any time.